# Unable to view Data base in data base inspector in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

[Check bottom left its showing database is closed but I am still running my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHzjc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Weird behavior.

If I use `Room` (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room ) to query the database, the database inspector works fine.

[image: Use room and live data to query the database]

But if I use `SQLiteDatabase` to query it, the database inspector shows "closed".

[image: If I use SQLiteDatabase, the database inspector not work.]

---

By the way, you can also use Facebook's `Stetho` libray to show the database content in the browser. http://facebook.github.io/stetho/